# website not appearing in a webview

Tags: android, url, webview, android-view

I am trying to open this [website](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Mumbra,+Thane,+Maharashtra/Mazgaon,+Mumbai,+Maharashtra/@19.0890476,72.804611,11z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x3be7bf117349510b:0xc8148b8a43075d71!2m2!1d73.0228173!2d19.1736147!1m5!1m1!1s0x3be7ce5ab292b941:0x19ab115c5e7876ac!2m2!1d72.8436024!2d18.9718388!3e3?hl=en) in my webview, but its coming out to be empty, following is my code,

```
 view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
    view.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Mumbra,+Thane,+Maharashtra/Mazgaon,+Mumbai,+Maharashtra/@19.0890476,72.804611,11z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x3be7bf117349510b:0xc8148b8a43075d71!2m2!1d73.0228173!2d19.1736147!1m5!1m1!1s0x3be7ce5ab292b941:0x19ab115c5e7876ac!2m2!1d72.8436024!2d18.9718388!3e3?hl=en"); //try js  alert
    view.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); // adding js alert support
```

what am i doing wrong here ?
Thank you for your suggestions.

full code
**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private WebView view; //membuat variabel view agar bisa akses method onKeyDown

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);// adding js alert support
        WebSettings settings = view.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        view.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
        view.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        view.loadUrl("https://moovit.com/?from=Mumbra&to=Dadar&fll=19.218316_73.087245&tll=18.976622_72.832794&metroId=3732&lang=en");
}



private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}

public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    //ketika disentuh tombol back
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && view.canGoBack()) {
        view.goBack(); //method goback() dieksekusi untuk kembali pada halaman sebelumnya
        return true;
    }
    // Jika tidak ada history (Halaman yang sebelumnya dibuka)
    // maka akan keluar dari activity
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

}
```

**layout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

Following is the manifest file in which i have give the permission to internet and i have also added hardware accelerated proprerty and set its value as true
**Manifest**

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: did you add internet permission in manifest file????

Comment: do you have internet permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you need change height and width of webview and it worked

Comment: nop still blank. I guess its the website fault. but i tried [link](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Mumbra,+Thane,+Maharashtra/Mazgaon,+Mumbai,+Maharashtra/@19.0890476,72.804611,11z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x3be7bf117349510b:0xc8148b8a43075d71!2m2!1d73.0228173!2d19.1736147!1m5!1m1!1s0x3be7ce5ab292b941:0x19ab115c5e7876ac!2m2!1d72.8436024!2d18.9718388!3e3?hl=en) still not working. Please check the updated question. Thank you for your help

Comment: Try replace `view.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());` to `view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());` and remove `view.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient())`

Comment: yes internet is working fine other websites like "www.google.com" are visible

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167110/discussion-between-meoscoder-and-yaseef-sheikh).